# How to filter form data based on a composite key in microsoft access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (Order) that has a one-to-many relationship with another table (ProductLine). The orders table has a primary key (OrderID) but the (ProductLine) table uses a composite key, combined of (CompanyID) and (OrderID).

I have a form that views all of the orders, with each order having a button that opens a new form and filters out product lines that match that order. The issue I have at the moment is that it's only filtering by using (OrderID), and not (CompanyID) AND (OrderID). This causes the issue of if 2 or more companies use the same (OrderID), their records are also shown.

This is the WHERE condition for the on-click event for the filter button:

`Where Condition ==("[OrderID]=" & [OrderID])`

Comment: `"[Orderid]=" & [OrderID] & " AND [CompanyID]=" & [CompanyID]` (note space before `AND`).

Comment: I tried something similar before and tested yours, but it doesn't work, just get the same result unfortunately

Comment: If you use a criteria as shown by @DarrenBartrup-Cook and a proper value for CompanyID, it can't in no way return records for another CompanyID.

Comment: I copy and pasted it, no clue why its not working, feels simple but can't work it out

Comment: Do you assign a unique identifier to each order received, perhaps with autonumber type field? Why not use that value as the fiilter criteria? Are you using macro? OrderID and CompanyID are both number type fields?

Comment: I use a composite key for an order, as the order ID is actually from the customer, we don't assign it. so only a composite key would uniquely identify an order.